# Facebook Javascript SDK: FB.login() doesn't work on Firefox/IE

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm building a very simple facebook application that just fetches a user's notifications from Facebook and also allows them to login. The URL is: http://widget.sidepage.co/_jump_frame.html

This works perfectly on Chrome - where the user is allowed to log in and authorize the app through a standard Facebook popup and once the app is authorized, it works well.

The problem is, on Firefox, clicking on the Facebook icon on the widget only opens a blank tab. There are no popup blocker warnings or JS errors thrown at the console.

Any pointers on how to fix this?

Comment: you should accept your past questions to make people answering you

Comment: Thanks for the input, will do that asap.

Comment: A weird issue: onclick="" doesn't work in Firefox/Chrome. If I replace it with onClick using a debugger, it begins to work. If I replace the onclick in the HTML file at the server, everytime the page reloads, it's replaced with an onclick instead of an onClick.

Comment: impossible, i use onclick="" on FF Chrome, Opera, it works, but maye not that is your problem, try deleting cache first of all

Comment: Cleared the cache, but no help. Here's what the html looks like around that area:  <a id="Facebook" class="item" onClick="handleClick()" href="#"> ...

Comment: Also, console.log inside the handleClick function doesn't put anything to the console.

Comment: try **href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="handleClick();"**

Comment: Tried that too, nothing. There's absolutely nothing being put at the console either - no error messages, nothing.

Comment: pasting your code will be usefull to you and to people wants to help you!

Comment: The entire js code is at widget.sidepage.co/js/fb_init.js and the a tag is exactly like you said.

Answer (score 2):

oh dude easy fix this is a Defining document compatibility issue...

and for what exactley you will need i suggest doing exactly what I did  to find out what your issue was run your app in firefox 16 and request to view the page source and observe the mark up as it is rendered to firefox and then do a little research on what it is that firefox 16 needs as far as a compatible input to run your code. It shouldn't be too bad. Best to you.. A few other sources. On this topic and legacy compatibility.

[helpful link](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/issues/378)

[helpful link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(v=VS.85).aspx)

hope that helps dude :)